# Celery workers do not perform django db update tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I am working on a dashboard which requires running long background tasks, and eventually updating a model in database. I am using `Celery` to perform the background operations

Here is my task function in `tasks.py`

```
@shared_task()
def generate_content_async(id):

    data = get_data() # long running operation
    
    section = Section.objects.get(id = id)
    section.data = data
    section.save()

    return f"Section with section id: {id} updated"
```

Please note that I am only updating the value of `data` in `Section` model. Everything in the code is working fine, and there are no issues, the background task finishes with success, but the database update does not work.

What would be the reason for such an issue?

TIA

I have tried using `transactions` to perform any database operations after commit, but did not work (this should not be an issue, as there are no ongoing transactions in my case).

**Edit 1**

Here is the `Section` model

```
class Section(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
    count = models.IntegerField(default= -1)
```

and, `data` is a value which contains comma separated keywords as a string ("Ebooks, Webinars, Case Studies, Comparison Articles, Whitepapers").

**Update**

I solved this issue. The issue was not with Django or Celery, but with the docker containers not sharing the same filesystem. On adding the bind volumes to both django and celery containers, the issue was solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have got a typo error when trying to get your section instance. Should be

```
section = Section.objects.get(id=section_id)
```

To handle does not exists error, you may add the following..

```
try:
  section = Section.objects.get(id=section_id)
  section.data = data
  section.save()
except Section.DoesNotExist:
  pass
```

Comment: I am sorry, I just updated my function definition. It was a big function so I copied the skeleton. Apologies

Comment: Can you verify that data is not blank

Comment: Yes data is not blank, it always has a value

Comment: can you share your Section model. And a sample of the data

Comment: I solved the issue, the problem was with docker containers and not celery or django